# FreeBSD: spdylay build error

Tags: compiling, freebsd, curl

I try to install the latest curl updates from ports (curl-7.37.1_2) with HTTP/2.0 support enabled and I need to build spdylay for that purpose, but I keep getting the following strange errors and cannot find information about them anywhere:

```
spdylay_ssl.o: In function `spdylay::connect_to(std::string const&, unsigned short)':
spdylay_ssl.cc:(.text+0x328): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
spdylay_ssl.o: In function `spdylay::make_listen_socket(std::string const&, unsigned short, int)':
spdylay_ssl.cc:(.text+0x56e): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
spdylay_ssl.o: In function `spdylay::ssl_handshake(ssl_st*, int)':
spdylay_ssl.cc:(.text+0xa25): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
spdylay_ssl.cc:(.text+0xabf): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
spdylay_ssl.o: In function `spdylay::nonblock_connect_to(std::string const&, unsigned short, int)':
spdylay_ssl.cc:(.text+0x1018): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
spdylay_ssl.o:spdylay_ssl.cc:(.text+0x1214): more undefined references to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [spdycat] Error code 1
```

How can I resolve this problem?

```
FreeBSD 9.2 x86_64
gcc version 4.9.2 20140820
OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

CC=gcc49
CXX=g++49
CPP=cpp49
CFLAGS+=-mssse3

WITH_PKGNG=yes
WITH_OPENSSL_PORT=yes
```